# Subspace contains two matrices with the same spectrums

Tags: matrix-analysis

Consider matrix subspace $\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$.
What is the minimum $d$ such that for any $d$-dimensional matrix subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, there exists two distinct matrix $M,N$ such that
$$
M^{+}M=N^{+}N
$$
here $M^{+}$ denotes the hermitian conjugate of $M$.

The distinct means that there is no $\lambda$ such that $M=\lambda N$.

Comment: $d=1$. Take $M=-N\neq 0$.

Comment: Maybe you want $M^*M=N^*N$ but where there is no $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}^\times$ with $M=\lambda N$.

Comment: @Joseph Oh yes, thanks.